# Backbone JS Create dynamic views and collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-routing, underscore.js-templating

I am a bit noob to backbone JS

I have this one code in which I need to list out the categories according to the json and list them out on the page.
Now when user clicks on any of the category list a new JSON attached to that category is fetched from the server and listed on the page.

My problem is I have listed out the categories but don't know how to get new JSON and display it on the screen by creating views and collection for new JSON dynamically depending on thecategory chosen.

**Here is my HTML Code**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Category list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="container">
    <h1>Category list</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class='categoryList'></div>
    <div class='selected_category'></div>
  </div>

   <script type="text/template" id="events-template">

            <% _.each( CategoryCollection, function(Category){ %>
              <div class='category'>
              <h2 class='<%= Category.get("category") %>'  > 
                    <%= Category.get("category") %>
                </h2> 
              </div>
            <% }); %> 
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="selectedCategory-template">
            <% _.each( SelectedCategoryCollection, function(selected_category){ %>
              <div class='category_list'>
                <%= selected_category.get("category") %>
              </div>
            <% }); %> 
    </script>



  </body>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var categoryJSON;

    var Category = Backbone.Model.extend();

    var CategoryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: Category,
      url: 'categories.json',
      parse: function (response) {
        categoryJSON = response;
        console.log(categoryJSON)
        return response;
      }
    });

    var CategoryAbout = Backbone.View.extend ({
      el: '.categoryList',
      render: function () {
        var that = this;
        // console.log(that)
        var eventCategory = new CategoryCollection();
        // console.log(eventCategory);
        eventCategory.fetch({
          success: function (CategoryCollection) {
            // console.log(CategoryCollection)
            var template = _.template($('#events-template').html(), {CategoryCollection: CategoryCollection.models});
            // console.log(template)
            that.$el.html(template);
          }
        })
      },
      events: {
        "click .category h2" : "doSearch"  
      },
      doSearch: function(event){
           // Button clicked
          console.log('clicked');
          console.log(event.toElement.className)
          router.navigate('/category/'+event.toElement.className, { trigger: true });
           // window.location.href = window.location.href + '/#/category/all';
      }

    });  

    var CategoryAbout = new CategoryAbout ();

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        '': 'home',
         "category/:categoryName": "getCategory",
      }     
    });

    var router = new Router();
    // console.log(router)
    router.on('route:home', function () {
      // console.log(this)
      console.log('home');
      CategoryAbout.render();
    });

    router.on('route:getCategory', function (categoryName) {

        console.log( "Category Name " + categoryName );
        var urlToFetch;
        for (var i = 0; i < categoryJSON.length; i++) {
            if(categoryJSON[i].category == categoryName)
            {
              urlToFetch = categoryJSON[i].data;
            }
        };
        console.log(urlToFetch);         
    });

    Backbone.history.start();


  </script>
```

**and the JSON file for Category**

```
 

    [

        {
            "category": "all",
            "data": "all.json"
        },
        {
            "category": "music",
            "data": "music.json"
        },
        {
            "category": "business",
            "data": "business.json"
        },
        {
            "category": "sports",
            "data": "sports.json"
        },
        {
            "category": "workshops",
            "data": "workshops.json"
        }

    ]
```

**and say that we have chosen workshop category then JSON of workshop is like this**

```
    {
        "request": {
            "venue": "0",
            "ids": "0",
            "type": "json",
            "city": "NY",
            "edate": 0,
            "page": 0,
            "keywords": "0",
            "sdate": 0,
            "category": "workshops",
            "city_display": "NY",
            "rows": 50
        },
        "count": 10,
        "item": [
            {
                "event_id": "230801950442480",
                "eventname": "Holiday special YES! course :) :)",
                "thumb_url": "http://graph.facebook.com/230801950442480/picture",
                "thumb_url_large": "http://graph.facebook.com/230801950442480/picture?type=large",
                "start_time": 1395943200,
                "start_time_display": "Thu Mar 27 2014 at 06:00 pm",
                "end_time": 1396213200,
                "end_time_display": "Sun Mar 30 2014 at 09:00 pm",
                "location": "NY,ABC street",
                "venue": {
                    "street": "",
                    "city": "NY",
                    "state": "XYZ",
                    "country": "PQR"
                },
                "label": "Tomorrow",
                "featured": 0
            },
            {
                "event_id": "230801950442480",
                "eventname": "Holiday special YES! course :) :)",
                "thumb_url": "http://graph.facebook.com/230801950442480/picture",
                "thumb_url_large": "http://graph.facebook.com/230801950442480/picture?type=large",
                "start_time": 1395943200,
                "start_time_display": "Thu Mar 27 2014 at 06:00 pm",
                "end_time": 1396213200,
                "end_time_display": "Sun Mar 30 2014 at 09:00 pm",
                "location": "NY,ABC street",
                "venue": {
                    "street": "",
                    "city": "NY",
                    "state": "XYZ",
                    "country": "PQR"
                },
                "label": "Tomorrow",
                "featured": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

thanks in advance.

**let me know if I am missing out any data**

Comment: Do you mean, you are not sure how to EDIT an item in Backbone.js?

Comment: not only item.
e.g I have selected a category 'workshop' and in workshop category's json should be fetched from the server added to the collection and the listing in the workshop category's json should be displayed on the page.

I am not getting is how to layout that new json in the exisiting view and collection so that it could be used in our template 'selectedCategory-template'.

Till now I could get is the clicked category type i.e 'workshop' etc.

**Thanks in advance **